# Which vs what. What to choose when?

Tags: relative-pronouns

Can someone give me clear rules when to use "what" and when "which" in case of sentences like " which/what "

Examples:

> "My access is arranged which/what saved a lot of time"
>
> "Studies have shown that strawberries contains X which/what have alarmed scientists"
>
> "I bought a car which/what will reduce my daily travel time."

Thanks.

Comment: These are all "which" sentences. "What" does not make sense here.

Comment: I give them as examples. I want to know when to use "what" and when to use "which"

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use "which" and "what" as a pronoun, to refer to the subject that precedes it.

However, "what" as a pronoun can only be used for interrogative reasons, to ask for information (i.e. in questions such as, "*What* is he doing?").

"Which" would work here, because it is used to refer to a specified antecedent (i.e. the subject of the sentence, such as "my success," "studies," and "a car").

Look at the dictionary definitions for [what](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/what?s=t) and [which](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/which?s=t) for more information.

Comment: _What_ and _which_ are part of grammar; they don't **have** any meaning because they're pronouns, so dictionaries are the wrong place to look. Dictionaries are good for words with meanings, like _etymology_ and _entomology_, but not for words that are part of the machinery of language. You need a grammar for that.

Comment: I agree with the answer provided, and I'd like to add that 'which' must be preceded by a comma since we are dealing with a non-defining relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

When "which" or "what" is used as a question, "which" is normally preferred when the options are limited, "what" is preferred when the options are unlimited.

For example:

```
What car do you prefer? (Unlimited options)
Which car do you prefer, the Volvo or the Mercedes? (Limited options)
```

Answer (score 1):

*What* can indeed function as a relative pronoun in nominal relative clauses, e.g. sentences like "I took what they offered me." One way to think of it is a less formal synonym of *that which*. E.g. *I eat what I like* = *I eat that which I like*. These examples are from Quirk's grammar.

More examples: https://www.englishgrammar.org/relative-pronoun/