# The use of the colon in context

Tags: punctuation

Tell me please if I used the colon correctly in the following sentence.

> What word does convey the meaning better: *connote* or *imply*?

I am not sure if it is a correct use of it. So tell me please what punctuation marlk should be used instead. Would the following sentence be better?

> Which word does convey the meaning better? *Connote* or *imply*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colons tend to be used to introduce a list of items, which is what it is doing in the case above. "Connote or Imply" is your list of answers, and therefore it is most natural to use a colon. [Ref.](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html)

The other thing to consider, is that "Connote or Imply" is not a sentence by itself, which is what the punctuation in option B is implying, since a "?" marks the end of a sentence much like a full stop. [Ref.](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/question-mark.html)

Lastly, the word *does* in your sentence, doesn't feel natural. Consider instead:

> **Which** word convey**s** the meaning better: connote or imply?

[Which vs what. What to choose when?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56550/which-vs-what-what-to-choose-when)

Answer (score 1):

I find it odd that there would be a question mark after a list of items. Generally, when a series of items are introduced as a list, they are simply stated—any question about the list would come before it or after it, but not in the same sentence.

Therefore, I would say you used the colon correctly as an introduction to a list—but I question the stylistic framing of the sentence.

I would rephrase your sentence:

> Consider these words: *connote* and *imply*. Which conveys the meaning better?

---

The sentence could also be rephrased to drop the use of the colon (to introduce a list) altogether:

> Does *connote* or *imply* convey the meaning better?